# Using d3.js is there a way to zero align two Y Axes with positive and negative values

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3, learning a lot. I have an issue I cannot find an example for:
I have two y axes with positive and negative values with vastly different domains, one being large dollar amounts the other being percentages.

The resulting graph from cobbling together examples looks really awesome with one slight detail, the zero line for each y axis is in a slightly different position. Does anyone know of a way in d3 to get the zero line to be at the same x position?

I would like these two yScales/axes to share the same zero line

```
// define yScale
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0])
.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.value_di1; }))
;

// define y2 scale
var yScale2 = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0])
.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.calc_di1_di2_percent; }))
;
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with sample data:

http://jsfiddle.net/jglover/XvBs3/1/

(the x-axis ticks look horrible in the jsfiddle example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there's unfortunately no way to do this neatly. D3 doesn't really have a concept of several things lining up and therefore no means of accomplishing it.

In your particular case however, you can fix it quite easily by tweaking the domain of the second y axis:

```
.domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.calc_di1_di2_percent; }), 0.7])
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XvBs3/2/).

Comment: Thanks Lars, I appreciate the example. My overall goal is to do this automatically for numerous, dynamic data sets. How did you arrive at the .7 value for changing the domain range. Is this something one just has to eye ball and determine or did you use some ratio against the other axis to determine?

Comment: I just eyeballed it. As I've said, there's no easy way to do this in general. You could calculate the ratio of the domain beyond a certain value (0 in your case) for different scales and then modify them such that these ratios are the same for all scales, but that might interfere with the logic that computes where tick labels should be placed, requiring further manual intervention there. It's easy if the scales are actually bounded by that specific value, but that obviously won't always be the case.

Comment: Thanks again for your further explanation. I have tried scaling the entire graph but was not happy with the results of the new "skewed" graph, it would/could create a lot of dead white space. I like the idea of simply moving one axis a tiny bit to line up, thus not skewing the graph by much. I'll keep playing with this idea to see if I can get something reliable to work.

Comment: To anyone interested in how this was eventually resolved. I used the following formula -> Ymin(pri)/Ymax(pri) = Ymin(sec)/Ymax(sec). Found here : http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AlignXon2Ys.html.  Solve for one of the points. This aligns our zero lines and solves our issue. As demonstrated in my updated jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/jglover/XvBs3/3/

Answer (score 0):

To make the 0 level the same position, a strategy is to equalize the length/proportion of the y axes.
Here are the concepts to the solution below:

1. The alignment of baseline depends on the length of the y axes.
2. To let all value shown in the bar, we need to extend the shorter side of the dimension, which compares to the other, to make the proportion of the two axes equal.

example:

```
// dummy data
const y1List = [-1000, 120, -130, 1400],
    y2List = [-0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.4];

// get proportion of the two y axes
const totalY1Length = Math.abs(d3.min(y1List)) + Math.abs(d3.max(y1List)),
    totalY2Length = Math.abs(d3.min(y2List)) + Math.abs(d3.max(y2List)),
    maxY1ToY2 = totalY2Length * d3.max(y1List) / totalY1Length,
    minY1ToY2 = totalY2Length * d3.min(y1List) / totalY1Length,
    maxY2ToY1 = totalY1Length * d3.max(y2List) / totalY2Length,
    minY2ToY1 = totalY1Length * d3.min(y2List) / totalY2Length;

// extend the shorter side of the upper dimension with corresponding value
let maxY1Domain = d3.max(y1List),
    maxY2Domain = d3.max(y2List);
if (maxY1ToY2 > d3.max(y2List)) {
    maxY2Domain = d3.max(y2List) + maxY1ToY2 - d3.max(y2List);
} else {
    maxY1Domain = d3.max(y1List) + maxY2ToY1 - d3.max(y1List);
}

// extend the shorter side of the lower dimension with corresponding value
let minY1Domain = d3.min(y1List),
    minY2Domain = d3.min(y2List);
if (minY1ToY2 < d3.min(y2List)) {
    minY2Domain = d3.min(y2List) + minY1ToY2 - d3.min(y2List);
} else {
    minY1Domain = d3.min(y1List) + minY2ToY1 - d3.min(y1List);
}

// finally, we get the domains for our two y axes
const y1Domain = [minY1Domain, maxY1Domain],
    y2Domain = [minY2Domain, maxY2Domain];
```