# D3 chart: How to align zero points of dual y axes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I´m trying to create a D3 line chart with two vertical y axes, one on the left and one on the right side. The domain of the left axis may have negative values, which means the zeropoint will be shifted upwards. I want to align the zeropoint of the right axis to the one of the left axix.  Similar as you can see here, but without the x axis moving upwards too:

[image]

So far, i tried to search for the html g element which represents the tick of the zero point:

```
<g id="tmp" class="y axis" transform="translate(30,0)" fill="red">
    <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,330)">
    <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,257.5)">
    <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,185)">
        <line x2="-5" y2="0">
        <text dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;" x="-8" y="0">0</text>
    </g>
```

What i need here is to extract the "185" height value in the transform attribute, so that i can use it for the range in the second axis.

That was just my basic idea how it could have been done. Does anyone know how do it technically with D3/Javascript? Or maybe even has a more elegant solution?

Comment: AFAIK this can't be done easily (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641547/using-d3-js-is-there-a-way-to-zero-align-two-y-axes-with-positive-and-negative-v).

Comment: Thanks for your link! The user jglover posted a solution which worked for me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using d3.js is there a way to zero align two Y Axes with positive and negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641547/using-d3-js-is-there-a-way-to-zero-align-two-y-axes-with-positive-and-negative-v)

Answer (score 1):

no need to split the axis - just make sure min/max of both axis' are proportional. You just need to identify the axis that must be extended.

In your example simply use a factor of 10 to have both axis perfectly aligned. Your left axis is extended to go up to 12 instead of the initial 10.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In your case distance from -4 (min value) to 0 on the left scale must match the distance from -40 (min value) to 0 on the right scale  and distance from 0 to 10 (max value) on the left scale  must match to the distance from 0 to 120 (max value) on the right scale.

To build the right axis you can use two axes ( one that goes from -40 to 0 and the other one that goes from 0 to 120 ). You can get the base line of the left axis by doing: `var base = leftAxis(0)`; The range of the first scale that you'll use to build the first axis will be  `[leftAxis(minVal), base]`, the range of the second scale will be  `[base, leftAxis(maxVal)]`.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but creating two instead of one axis brings another problem: How can i draw a line corresponding to both of them? The only way i can think of would be to split the data array i´m using into positive and negative values and create also two lines instead of just one, but even then it could be complicated to make sure both lines match at their endpoints....

Comment: Exactly, you would have to split axis in two. Ranges that I provided in the answer will match at their endpoints. The only thing you'll need to take care about is removing an axis tick corresponding to zero on one of the axis, so that only one axis show zero tick.